# How Do I Add Value To All Previous Values In Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, arraycollection

Lets say I have the following array:

```
my_array = [1, 5, 8, 11, -6]
```

I need to iterate over this array and add the values prior to the current value together.  An example will probably be easier to understand. I need to return an array that should look something like this:

```
final_array = [1, 6, 14, 25, 19]
```

I have tried doing something like this:

```
my_array.collect {|value| value + previous_values }
```

But obviously that doesn't work because I can't figure out how to get the previous values in the array.

I am a programming noob so this might be easier than I am making it.  I am pretty sure I need to use either collect or inject, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks everyone.  I will give these a shot.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your own attempt at it with `collect` was already very close; just keep summing the previous values as you go.

```
my_array = [1, 5, 8, 11, -6]
previous_values = 0
my_array.collect { |value| previous_values += value }
# => [1, 6, 14, 25, 19]
```

Answer (score 9):

My very first instinct was: "That's obviously a scan (aka prefix-sum), so that should be easy":

```
[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].scan(:+)
```

Obviously, I've been reading way too much Haskell and Scala lately, because *there is no `Enumerable#scan`* in Ruby … yet:

```
module Enumerable
  def scan(initial=first, &block)
    [initial].tap {|res| 
      reduce {|acc, el| 
        block.(acc, el).tap {|el|
          res << el
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

If you want `Enumerable#scan` to behave like `Enumerable#reduce`, i.e. take an optional initial argument and an optional symbol, we need to enhance our version slightly with some argument massaging code stolen from Rubinius's `Enumerable#reduce`:

```
module Enumerable
  def scan(initial=nil, sym=nil, &block)
    args = if initial then [initial] else [] end
    unless block_given?
      args, sym, initial = [], initial, first unless sym
      block = ->(acc, el) { acc.send(sym, el) }
    end
    [initial || first].tap {|res| 
      reduce(*args) {|acc, el| 
        block.(acc, el).tap {|e|
          res << e
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

With this enhanced version, the example above now works:

```
p [1, 5, 8, 11, -6].scan(:+)
# => [1, 6, 14, 25, 19]
```

If you have this kind of problem again, in another language, remember the terms *scan* and *prefix-sum*, such functions are usually pretty common. I don't quite understand why Ruby doesn't have them already.

Comment: I share your instinct.... It's fairly ridiculous this hasn't been a builtin since the beginning...

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 0
[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].map {|a| x = x +a }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_array.each_index{|i| my_array[i] += my_array[i-1] if i>0 }
```

or

```
my_array.inject([]){|memo, item| memo << item + memo.last.to_i }
```

Comment: inject is unlikely to work as memo.last will return nil initially.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought it will convert automatically to int, but no, so added explicitly `to_i`.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex having to make a special case of the first element in both solutions.

Comment: @Arkku Actually it is necessary to add `if i>0` in first solution, because otherwise `my_array[i-1]` will be `my_array[0-1] = my_array[-1]`, which is last element of array.

Comment: After: Yes, I know, that's why it seems unnecessarily complex; the first element becomes a special case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
my_array = [1, 5, 8, 11, -6]
final_array = []

my_array.inject(0) {|res, it| final_array << res + it; res + it}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a gem for this that pre-allocates the result array. The operation is very fast, even for Enumerables with a large number of elements. Unlike solutions using Enumerable#map, the syntax is exactly like that of Enumerable#reduce, and can optionally use Enumerable#reduce under the hood in case you have monkey-patched #reduce. The name was taken from Clojure's function of the same name.

https://rubygems.org/gems/reductions

To install:

```
$ gem install reductions
```

To use:

```
require 'reductions'

[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].reductions(:+)            #=> [1, 6, 14, 25, 19]
[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].reductions{|a| a + b}     #=> [1, 6, 14, 25, 19]

# With an inital value:
[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].reductions(1,:+)          #=> [1, 2, 7, 15, 26, 20]
[1, 5, 8, 11, -6].reductions(1){|a| a + b}  #=> [1, 2, 7, 15, 26, 20]
```